# wordpress show unserialize data in a smart way

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

In wordpress I have stored the data in database as serialize method. Now I have fetched the data in an array. So the code is like this

```
global $wpdb;
 $results = wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `table` where `id` = 3");
 foreach($results as $result) {
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
 }
```

This one is getting me data like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => a:3:{i:1;s:8:"test1";i:2;s:8:"test2";i:0;s:0:"test3";}
            [page] => a:3:{i:1;s:3:"dsa";i:2;s:4:"dsds";i:0;s:0:"sdvdsvds";}
        )

)
```

Now I want to count the values and want to show all the values in listing. Here you can see I have 3 values for title and page. So I took title as counter. So I made like this

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $count = count(unserialize($result->title)); // This gave 3
    for( $i = 0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        echo '<li></li>'; // This gave me 3 li's that I wanted
    }
 }
```

Now to get all the values for title and page I need again foreach and unserialize method. So can someone kindly tell me what is the nice and smart way to show the data for title and words here(inside li's). Any suggestions and help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be 90% of the way there, you simply need to show the data.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `table` where `id` = 3" );

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    $titles = unserialize($result->title); 
    foreach( $titles as $title ) { // Loop through it
        echo '<li>'. $title ."</li>\n"; 
    }
}
```

I have removed your call to `count`, as if it's only used to work out how may times to loop through then you won't need it.  You can use a `foreach` loop to loop through all items in an array.

I added a line break (`\n`) after every `</li>`, this is only to make the generated markup a little more readable.

I have also added spaces after each opening parenthesis and before each closing, this is inline with the WordPress coding standard.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But is there any smarter way to show all the data. As because by doing your method have to use foreach loop for every data like title, word etc

Comment: If you need to display it, that is the best way.  If you're doing it with a handful of rows then it's not a problem.  If you're doing it to hundreds or thousands or rows then you'll want to address how you're storing your data.  Either way, this is the best way.

Comment: Yes I am storing 10 rows at a time in the database in serialize. Its a long data. So I want the smarter way.

Comment: Without changing the way the data is stored this is the smartest way you'll be able to do it.